# Выбор языка для работы с mysql

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, база-данных, node.js

Создаю простой онлайн проект, ради этого изучаю нужные для написания языки (html, css, php (средне), java script и jquery (уже разобрался и пишу на них))и не могу разобраться сейчас, только с 1 деталью - как работать с БД в рамках моих задач.

Цель: сайт с личным аккаунтом, где ты можешь хранить некоторые численные/буквенные данные и изменять их без перезагрузки страницы ( с аккаунтом или без ). Скажем на сайте есть купоны 100 штук, ты забрал 1, на сайте уже пишется остаток 99. Ты можешь брать их бесплатно или за валюту аккаунта.

На чём сейчас я : Сделан сайт, на js сделал изменение количества купонов через обычную переменную. Сейчас захотел сделать не переменную, а данные из БД mysql, которые будут при нажатии перезаписываться. И не могу разобраться, как лучше это сделать.

- 1.Первое что нашёл node.js - по отзывам и описанию - самое оптимальное, но как быть с хостингом? Придётся выбирать только тот хостинг, где поддерживается node.js как я понял.
- 2. ajax - он работает как я понял с xml базами и он не подойдёт для реализации аккаунтов на сайте.
- 3. php/mysql - отличный вариант для регистрации на сайте, нашёл кучу уроков как сделать, НО подойдёт ли он для механики "забирания купонов" ( объясню почему, хотелось бы на сайте сделать динамические кнопки, действия - благодаря которым пользователь будет что-то делать и будут изменяться значения в БД, динамические кнопки, анимации,может что-то типа мини-игры и.т.д. Я научился делать это в js, но не нашёл подобного на чистом php )

Итог: Знающие люди, кто делал подобное, дайте пожалуйста совет/ссылку, на чем реализовать работу с БД( как я понимаю лучшая бд MYSQL) в данном проекте ( регистрация/аккаунты + работа с БД при помощи динамических кнопок, анимаций,мини-игр на сайте ). Спасибо.

Comment: У вас немного каша в голове сейчас. Сначала разберитесь, как работает клиент-сервер архитектура. Потом многие вопросы отпадут сами собой.

Comment: Спасибо, согласен. Если у Вас есть ссылки на информацию/примеры ,буду благодарен.

Answer (score 0):

Уважаемый Роман,

в комментариях правильно пишут про "кашу в голове".

Давайте я напишу здесь немного теории.

1. Когда вы делаете сайт, то то, что видит пользователь - называется "фронтэндом".
   Фронтенд состоит из html, css и js, исполняющегося в браузере пользователя.

Вообще говоря, у такого кода много ограничений. Самое важное в Ваше задаче - нужно, чтобы было некое центральное хранилище информации, чтобы клиенты получали одинаковую копию информации с сервера и видели изменения в виде "кто то забрал купон, осталось 99"

2. Для того, чтобы так все работало - нужен "бэкэнд". Это - то, что работает на сервере (на хостинге, который Вы выберите).
3. Обычно (в супер - подавляющем большинстве слчаев) фронтэнд не взаимодействуетс базой данных напрямую.
4. есть две популярные технологии построения сайтов, котрые исторически сложились: "server-side templates" и то, что назывется "single page applications".

Первая технология - более старая, и использовалась в то время, когда js  в современном виде еще не существовало, а его поддержка в разных браузерах сильно отличалась. Фактически, при этом страницы сайта генерируюся на сервере (из шаблонов) и уезжают к пользоваетлю по HTTP соединению.

Эта технология останется с нами еще надолго, но вторая - SPA - выглядит гораздо привлекательнее и проще, особенно с точки зрения начинающего разработчика. Кроме того, она даёт гораздо бОльшую интерактивность.

SPA можно в двух словах описать так: "С сайта загружается страница и начальный js. Как только этот js начинает выполняться, он занимается всем, что делается на сторооне пользователя: меняет страницу, применяет "клиентские шаблоны (привет ангуляру и Vue.js), а к серверу обращается только за данными. В большинстве случаев обращение происходит по REST - протоколу, иногда - когда нужна еще бОльшая интерактивность - по вебсокету. При этом сервер функционально представляет из себя простой файловый хостинг - надо же с чего то загрузить самую первую страницу - и набор "ручек", за котрые можно подергать (при помощи REST), чтобы получить данные или выполнить какие то действия на серверной стороне.

Теперь у Вас есть достаточно ключевых слов для того, чтобы разумно погуглить и разобраться в дальнейшем.

Одиин из кратчайших путей - это использование node.js. Очень развитая экосистема, очень плавный "порог вхождения" и очень большое комьюнити.

Успехов вам!

Comment: Спасибо! Стало чуть понятнее и бууду искать по ключевым словам в гугле.